# Calculating delay from 3 nested loops

Tags: assembly, avr, timing

My exercise: •Calculate the maximum delay possible using three loops @ 1 MHz clock frequency. (Answer 49.94 s)

```
delay:   ldi    r23,$FF          ;Initialise 3rd loop counter 
loop3:   ldi    r24,$FF          ;Initialise 2nd loop counter 
loop2:   ldi    r25,$FF          ;Initialise 1st loop counter 
loop1:   dec         r25              ;Decrement the 1st loop counter 
          brne   loop1            ;and continue to decrement until 1st loop counter = 0 
          dec    r24               ;Decrement the 2nd loop counter 
          brne   loop2            ;If the 2nd loop counter is not equal to zero repeat the 1st loop, else continue 
          dec    r23
          brne   loop3 
      ret                   ;Return
```

I'm trying to calculate the maximum delay using those 3 loops the answer apparently is 49.94 s and I'm really struggling it was much simpler with 2 nested loops.

Here is what I've tried, but the answer is way off.

```
33*((255*3)-1) + 17*((33*3)-1) + 11*3
```

`ldi` - 1 clock cycle, `brne` 1 or 2 clock cycles

Architecture: ATmega8535

Comment: `ldi    r23,$FF          ;Initialise 3rd loop counter 17` <-- Your comment doesn't match the code. You're also using 17 and 33 in your attempted calculation. Where did you get those values from? And if you wanted the maximum possible delay, shouldn't you initialize the counters to 0?

Comment: which architecture is that? add it to the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, the longest loop would load `0` not `FF` to the counter, but let's stick with `FF` so we get the expected answer. With `FF` the loop runs 254 times and exits on the 255th.

The general formula is `1` for `ldi`, `(n-1) * (body + 3)` for the full iterations (`1` for `dec` and `2` for `brne`) and `(body + 2)` for the final one (`1` for`dec` and `1` for not taken `brne`). `body` means whatever is in the loop body, for the innermost loop that's `0` as it's empty.

Thus, for the innermost loop: `1 + 254 * (0 + 3) + (0 + 2) = 765`.
For the middle loop, the `body` is the `765` from the innermost loop, thus we have: `1 + 254 * (765 + 3) + (765 + 2) = 195840`.
For the outermost loop the `body` is the `195840` from the middle loop, thus
we have: `1 + 254 * (195840 + 3) + (195840 + 2) = 49939965` which is the expected answer.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with the (body +3) now so ldi runs once so 1 then dec and brne runs 254 times so wouldn't it be 2*254 on the final loop brne is 2 so the whole thing would look like 1 + 2*254 + 2

Comment: You swapped the times for the `brne`, it takes 2 clocks when it jumps back, that is in the loop, and 1 clock when it does not jump, that is the last iteration.

Comment: I got it now thanks :) I don't mean to burden you but could you tell me what would the delay be for e.g. loops r23, $06, r24, $FD, r23, $DD; It's harder to follow with all the same numbers my answer for those ones is 1174836 clock cycles I'm trying to recreate it in Excel so I don't have to calculate it every time

Comment: I got `1011006` but might have messed up :)

Comment: you are right thanks again! I've messed up the order of loops