# How do AVR Assembly BRNE delay loops work?

Tags: loops, assembly, delay, avr

An [online delay loop generator](http://www.bretmulvey.com/avrdelay.html) gives me this delay loop of runtime of 0.5s for a chip running at 16MHz.

The questions on my mind are:

1. Do the branches keep branching if the register becomes negative?
2. How exactly does one calculate the values that are loaded in the beginning?

   ```
       ldi  r18, 41
       ldi  r19, 150
       ldi  r20, 128
   L1: dec  r20
       brne L1
       dec  r19
       brne L1
       dec  r18
       brne L1
   ```

Comment: 1. Look up what `brne` does in the instruction set reference.  I assume it's taken when the result is non-zero, regardless of positive or negative.  So just think of the loops as using unsigned counters.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23478769/547981) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35750663/547981)

Comment: You have to compute the instruction cycles to calculate the time this loop consumes. This loop cycles the label `L1:` 0x00299680 (2,725,504) times. (0x29 = 41d, 0x96 = 150d, 0x80 = 128d). The time you compute using cycles is not valid if ISR (interrupt sub routine) are executed during the loop; You may use the opportune instruction to disable ISR during the delay loop.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your questions exactly:

1: The [DEC](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_DEC.html) instruction doesn't know about 'signed' numbers, it just decrements an 8-bit register.  The miracle of twos complement arithmetic makes this work at the wraparound (0x00 -> 0xFF, is the same bit pattern as 0 -> -1).  The DEC instruction also sets the Z flag in the status register, which [BRNE](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_BRNE.html) uses to determine if branching should happen.

2:  You can see from the AVR manual that DEC is a single cycle instruction.  BRNE is also a single cycle when not branching, and 2 cycles when branching.  therefore to compute the time of your loop, you need to count the number of times each path will be taken.

Consider a single DEC/BRNE loop:

```
    ldi r8 0
L1: dec r8
    brne L1
```

This loop will execute exactly 256 times, which is 256 cycles of DEC, and 512 cycles of BRNE, for a total of 768 cycles.  At 16MHz, that's 48us.

Wrapping that in an outer delay loop:

```
    ldi r7 10
    ldi r8 0
L1: dec r8
    brne L1
    dec r7
    brne L1
```

You can see that the outer loop counter will decrement every time the inner loop counter hits 0.  Thus in our example the outer loop DEC/BRNE will happen 10 times(for 768 cycles), and the inner loop will happen 10 x 256 times so the total time for this loop is 10 x 48us + 48us for 528us. Similarly for 3 nested loops.

From here, it's trivial to figure out how many times each loop should execute to achieve the desired delay.  It's the largest number of iterations the outer loop can do less than the desired time, then taking that time out, do the same for the next nested loop, and so on until the inner most loop fills up the tiny amount left.

Answer (score 3):

> How exactly does one calculate the values that are loaded in the beginning?

Calculate total amount of cycles => 0.5s * 16000000 = 8000000

Know the total cycles of r20 and r19 loops (from zero to zero), AVR registers are 8 bit, so a full loop is 256 times (`dec 0 = 255`). `dec` is 1 cycle. `brne` is 2 cycles when condition (branch) happens, 1 cycle when not.

So the most inner loop:

```
L1: dec  r20
    brne L1
```

Is from zero to zero (`r20=0`): 255 * (1+2) + 1 * (1+1) = 767 cycles (255 times the branch is taken, 1 time it goes through).

---

The second wrapping loop working with `r19` is then: 255 * (767+1+2) + 1 * (767+1+1) = 197119 cycles

The single `r18` loop when branch is taken is then 197119+1+2 = 197122 cycles. (197121 when branch is not taken = final exit of delay loop, I will avoid this -1 by a trick in next step).

Now this is almost enough to calculate initial `r18`, let's adjust the total cycles first by the O(1) code, that's three times `ldi` instruction, which takes 1 cycle: total2 = 8000000 - (1+1+1) + 1 = 7999998  ... wait, what is the last +1 there? That's fake additional cycle to delay, to make the final `r18` loop pretend it costs same as non-final, i.e. 197122 cycles.

And that's it, the initial `r18` must be enough to wait **at least** 7999998 cycles: `r18 = (7999998 + 197122 - 1) div 197122 = 41`. The " + 197122 - 1" part will make sure the abundant cycles fits constraint: `0 <= abundant_cycles < 197122` (remainder by 197122 division).

`41 * 197122 = 8082002`  ... this is too much, but now we can shave the extra cycles down by setting up also `r19` and `r20` to particular values, to fine-tuned the delay. So how much is to be shaved off? `8082002 - 7999998 = 82004` cycles.

The single `r19` loop takes 770 cycles when branching and 769 when exiting, so again let's avoid the 769 by adjusting 82004 to only 82003 to be shaved off. `82003 div 770 = 106`: 106 `r19` loops can be skipped, `r19 = 256 - 106 = 150`. Now this will shave 81620 cycles, so 82003 - 81620 = 383 cycles more to be shaved off.

The single `r20` loop takes 3 cycles when branching and 2 when exiting. Again I will take into account the exiting loop being only 2 cycles -> 383 => 382 to shave off. And `382 div 3 = 127`, remainder 1. `r20 = 256 - 127 = 129` and do one less to shave additional 3 cycles (to cover that remainder) = 128. Then 2 cycles (3-1) wait is missing to make it a full 8mil.

So:

```
    ldi  r18, 41
    ldi  r19, 150
    ldi  r20, 128
L1: dec  r20
    brne L1
    dec  r19
    brne L1
    dec  r18
    brne L1
```

According to my calculations should wait exactly 8000000-2 cycles (if not interrupted by something else).

Let's try to verify:

Initial `r20`: 127*3 + 1*2 = 383 cycles
Initial `r19`: 1*(383+1+2) + 148*(767+1+2) + 1*(767+1+1) = 115115 cycles
(that's initial `r20` incomplete cycle one time, then 149 times full time `r20` cycle with the final one being -1 due to exiting `brne`)
The `r18` total: 1*(115115+1+2) + 39*(197119+1+2) + 1*(197119+1+1) = 7999997 cycles.

And the three `ldi` are +3 cycles = 7999997+3 = 8000000.

And the missing 2 cycles are nowhere to be seen, so I made somewhere a mistake.

As you can see, the math behind is reasonably simple, but very mundane to do by hand, and prone to mistakes...

Ah, I think I know where I did the mistake. When I'm shaving off the abundant cycles, the termination loop is not involved (that's part of the actual delay process), so I shouldn't have adjusted the to_shave_off cycles by -1. Then After `r19 = 106` I would have still to shave off 384 cycles, and that's exactly 384/3 = 128 loops to shave off from `r20 = 256-128 = 128`. No remainder, no missing cycle, perfect 8mil.

If you have trouble to follow this reverse calculation, try it other way, imagine 2 bit registers (0..3 values only), and do on paper similar loop with r18=r19=r20=2, and count the cycles manually to see how it is evolving. .. i.e. 3x ldi = +3, dec r20,brne,dec r20,brne(skip) = +5 cycles, dec r19, brne = +3, ... etc.

Edit: and this was explained before by Jester in his links. And I'm too lazy to clean this up down to some simple formula to create your own online calculator.

Comment: Obviously this computation is valid only if the MCU doesn't execute ISR ... :)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini yeah, and there's no simple way out of it, as long as time managing is naive cycles-counting, it is hopeless. Some kind of timer-on-chip data is needed to create less accurate, but more reliable time delay loops. Then again, if this is some kind of very specialized system doing just single task and needed absolutely perfect timing, it's a valid approach to disable all interrupts and let only this perfectly timed code to run, then the accuracy will be same as the crystal freq accuracy in the CPU (which may be not that great? I probably wouldn't use it for anything important).

Comment: The AVR MCUs have good counters with a lot of settings. One capability a programmer may use is to set a number of counts that trigger an ISR when the count elapses... ;)

Comment: It's not too hard to disable ISR when you're using AVR!

Comment: In some AVR (I remember not all) there're the `CLI` and `SEI` instructions. Where these instructions are not present it's possible to set/reset a bit, that indicates the global ISR are or aren't enabled, on the SREG register! :)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini as I'm not AVR programmer, I'm not aware of common timer features available across the common boards (as I understand, there're so many different chip types, that you can build pretty much any combination, including chips where no timer is available?). Consider adding some detailed answer how to use interrupt-after-cycles timer, may be nice to have different approach available on SO site. Then again, it's lot of work (to produce good answer), and OP didn't ever respond, and I'm not sure how good this question is for related search queries... Maybe such answer exists already:)